# How to calculate the length of a string converted from a map field in hive?

Tags: hive

I want to calcute the string length of a map field from a hive table using hive ql.

Anybody knows how to?

Is there any method that can convert a map field to a string using hive ql?

thanks!

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-udf.html

Comment: Thanks! I have already read it. I have tried function:length java_method reflect. But they only accept primitive type arguments, can not handle the map.